# what is the output and why the pointer in function does not affect the code?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, pass-by-value

why the op is 20 ?? not 10 ? I think the op should be 10 but I don't know what happened? can you please explain it step by step

```
void fun(int *ptr)
{
    int q=10;
    ptr=&q;
}

int main()
{
    int r=20;
    int *p=&r;
    fun(p);
    printf("%d",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. `ptr=&q` changes a **local** variable and not the caller's variable. 2. `q` is also a local variable and it no longer exists after the function exits. Trying to access that memory in the caller is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: C is *pass-by-value* so `fun` receives a *copy of* the pointer from `main()` in `ptr` where you try and change the *address-held-by* `ptr` rather than the *value-at-the-original-address* (e.g. `*ptr = q;`). Changes made to the address held by the copy are lost on function return.

Comment: @kaylum, do you want to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

- Values of function arguments are copies of what is passed from caller. Modifying in callee will not affect caller's local variables.
- Non-static local variables will vanish on exiting its scope. Therefore, you must not dereference pointers to them after that.

To obtain 10, your code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int **ptr) /* pass a pointer to modify caller's local variable */
{static int q=10; /* add static to prevent it from vanishing */
*ptr=&q; /* dereference the pointer */
}

int main()
{int r=20;
int *p=&r;
fun(&p); /* pass the pointer */
printf("%d",*p);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is `p` and `r` (addresses are *for instance* based)

```
 ----------------      ----------------      ----------------
 | r         20 |      | p       1234 |      | q         10 | 
 ----------------      ----------------      ----------------
 ^                     ^                     ^
 |_ Address of r       |_ Address of p       |_ Address of q
    = 1234                = 9876                = 12121
```

To `fun()`,

```
void fun(int *ptr) {
   int q = 10;
   ptr = &q;
}
```

you provide `p` as `ptr` (ie `1234`), then set `ptr` to the address of `q`

```
fun:  ptr = 12121
```

then fun ends, and `ptr` dies with it, the memory didn't change for `r`

To change something you have to pass the *address* of that thing. Even if it is a pointer.

Giving the address of `p` to `fun`

```
fun( &p );
```

and changing `fun()` to accept a pointer to pointer

```
void fun(int **ptr) {  // <== pointer to pointer
   int q = 10;
   *ptr = &q;          // <== change r indirectly
}
```

here, `ptr` has the address of the pointer `p`, ie `9876`

```
*ptr = &q; // changes the value of `r`
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s basically because of two reasons:

1. `p` in `main()` and `ptr` in `fun()` are two **different** pointers, and
2. You pass `p` by **value**, not by **reference**.

---

At the function call:

```
fun(p);
```

you just pass `p` by **value**; Means it passes the address of `r` (what is actually the value of `p`) to `ptr`.

With `ptr = &q;` in `fun()` you just assign the address of `q` to `ptr`, but not to `p`.

Therefore, the output of dereferencing `p` at:

```
printf("%d",*p);
```

is of course `20`, as `p` still point to `r` -> the value of `p` didn´t changed.

---

If you instead pass `p` by reference and declare `ptr` as pointer to pointer (`**`), plus qualify `q` with `static` qualifier (because function-local `auto`matic variables will be destroyed after the function is executed once):

```
void fun(int **ptr)            // ptr is declared as pointer to pointer to int.
{
    static int q = 10;         // q is static -> It won´t get destroyed after returning from `fun()`.
    *ptr = &q;                 // dereferencing ptr to assign the address of q to p.
}

int main()
{
    int r = 20;
    int *p = &r;
    fun(&p);                   // Notice the `&` to gain the address of `p`, not `r`.
    printf("%d",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be `10` as we actually assigned the address of `q` to `p`.

As a side note: It is considered as bad programming style to refer to `static`-qualified function-local variables from a caller. I just showed this to you for the educational purpose and to show the difference to your provided code.

Try to assign an object pointed to in the caller, here f.e. `r`, by a passed pointer inside of the called function, here `ptr`, with the actual value of the object in the called function, here `q`.